# Need nested enums for grouping

Tags: java, enums, nested

I need to define some "metadata" in enum. Basically, I have multiple parameters, which are present when some parent parameter is present.

For example:

```
enum Param {
    ADDPERSON("addperson", false), 
    DELETEPERSON("deleteperson", false);

    String name;
    boolean required;

    private Param(String name, boolean required) {
        this.name = name;
        this.required = required;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now for `Param.ADDPERSON` I have other param definitions associated with this enum i.e. `NAME, EMAIL` etc.

Ideal would be to be able to call `Param.ADDPERSON.NAME`. This doesn't seem possible, except with this workaround with inner static enum:

```
enum Param {
    ADDPERSON("addperson", false), 
    DELETEPERSON("deleteperson", false);

    String name;
    boolean required;

    private Param(String name, boolean required) {
        this.name = name;
        this.required = required;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static enum AddPerson {
        NAME("name", true), 
        EMAIL("email", true);

        String name;
        boolean required;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        private AddPerson(String name, boolean required) {
            this.name = name;
            this.required = required;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can use `Param.AddPerson.NAME`, but it's not a clean solution + I need to be able to grab child enums, for example get all child enums of `ADDPERSON`.

The point is to have these params centralized so that I can perform "generic validation" on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to other enum constants inside the same enum.
For example, you can maintain a set of parameters inside ADDPERSON or DELETEPERSON and look them up using a method call such as parameters();

```
public enum Param {

    NAME("name", true, true, EnumSet.noneOf(Param.class)),
    EMAIL("email", true, true, EnumSet.noneOf(Param.class)),
    ADD_PERSON("addperson", false, false, EnumSet.of(NAME, EMAIL)),
    DELETE_PERSON("deleteperson", false, false, EnumSet.of(NAME));

    final String name;
    final boolean required;
    final boolean isParameter;
    final EnumSet<Param> parameters;

    private Param(
            final String name,
            final boolean isParameter,
            final boolean required,
            final EnumSet<Param> parameters) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isParameter = isParameter;
        this.required = required;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public Set<Param> parameters() {
        return EnumSet.copyOf(parameters);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```